# Full Screen Application Not Working Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-manifest

I am creating an application where it needs to be in full screen all the time so that the status bar is not shown and the navigation back bar should show.

Here is what I am doing currently:

1. AndroidManifest.xml

   ```
   <application
        android:name="ApplicationClass"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:configChanges="locale|orientation|layoutDirection"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:resizeableActivity="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

   ......

   <activity
        android:name=".HomePageActivity"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">


   <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|layoutDirection"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
   ```
2. styles.xml

   ```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
       <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
       <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
       <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
       <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
       <item name="android:layoutDirection">ltr</item>
       <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
       <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
       <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
       <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
       <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
       <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto</item>
       <item name="fontFamily">@font/roboto</item>
     </style>

     <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
       <item name="android:layoutDirection">ltr</item>
       <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
       <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
       <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
       <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
       <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
       <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@android:anim/fade_out</item>
     </style>
   ```
3. Splash Screen Activity Code:

   ```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.noanim, R.anim.activity_fade_out);
   ```
4. HomePage Activity Code:

   ```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.noanim, R.anim.activity_fade_out);
   ```
5. activity_home_page.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_home_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bb_bottom_bar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white">
```

**The MAIN Issue:**

[image: Upper Screen has blank space and the lower screen has same]

Please help what am I doing wrong, I almost tried everything I could but couldn't get the solution. I just need the status bar to go away and the navigation bar to remain there it is with the bottom bar tab above my navigation bar.

Please help!!

Comment: pls attach final output image

Comment: @BADSHAH already added as the Main Issue screenshot.

Comment: I have added answer pls check it and apply solution.

Comment: have you applied my answer it's working or not..?

Comment: @BADSHAH I tried the other way and for now it's working. Couldn't check your answer. But will check soon.